# Mysql implicit type casting generates wrong results

Tags: mysql

I have a script that generates a SQL query from two given parameters: field and value. In the end, it generates something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE <field> IN <value>;
```

So far, nothing serious. But now imagine this: You have a field with strings in it, sometimes consisting only of numbers, sometimes not. And now you give a value of 123:

```
SELECT string FROM table WHERE string = 123;
```

Due to MySQL Autocasting, this query will result any row with either 123 in it **or a string starting with 123**. Is there any way to disable this kind of auto casting of part strings? I want to only get results that contain **exactly** the given value (cast or not)

**Simple Test SQL**
This small select shows the problem:

```
SELECT '123abc' IN (123, 234, 'xyz');
```

Note: Since my SQL is script generated, I can not simply cast my value to string or encase it in upper quotes. The ideal solution would be to only manipulate the operator to return **equals**, no matter what type.

Comment: Use MySQL cast function. SELECT '123abc' = cast(123 as char);

Comment: This is probably not an option since my real query (first sample) uses IN and the generated query might also refer to a column that actually is of INT type. In that case my cast would probably have a bad effect on key use?

Comment: Using IN (a, b, c, ...) is the same as column = a or column = b or ... MySQL optimizes/rewrites this query before execution. It also depends ofcourse if you have an index on that column. Bad effect on key use is if you use like this: column like '%keyword' (does not use index). Using like this: column like 'keyword%' (does use index) See page 10 at http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-full-text-search-throwdown.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Quote your arguments, if you expect to use them as a string.
Check how it works:

```
SELECT '123abc' = '123'
```

If you use autogenerator to automatically quote values when building a query - choose one that supports database schema definitions and quote/cast value according to column type, instead of making decisions upon seeming value types, as in your example.

Comment: I am already using some kind of auto generator. This one determines the type of the given value and then casts appropriatly, not considering the target column as it might be a temporary one unknown to any generator. So in my case, 123 qualifies as a number and will be taken without quotes, nothing I can do about that.